# Should graphene classes be repetitive like this?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I have the following mutation classes to for CRUDing a model. However, I have another model that I need to do the exact same classes on it. Should I create the exact same classes again with other names like `class CreateComment`, `class UpdateComment` and `class DeleteComment` or there is a way to make reusable classes with graphene?

```
class CreatePost(graphene.Mutation):
      class Arguments:
            description = graphene.String(required=True)
      post = graphene.Field(schema.Posts)
      @classmethod
      def mutate(cls, root, info, description):
            post = models.Post(description=description,added_by=info.context.user)
            post.save()
            return CreatePost(post=post)
class UpdatePost(graphene.Mutation):
      # owner(added_by)+admin can update and delete
      class Arguments:
            id = graphene.Int(required=True)
            description = graphene.String()
      post = graphene.Field(schema.Posts)
      @classmethod
      def mutate(cls, root, info, id, description):
            post = models.Post.objects.get(id=id)
            if (info.context.user == post.added_by):
                  post.description = description
                  post.save()
                  return CreatePost(post=post)
            else:
                  "Only the owner of the post and the admin(website's wonr) can edit and delet this post"
                  
                  

class DeletePost(graphene.Mutation):
       # owner(added_by)+admin can update and delete
      class Arguments:
            id = graphene.Int(required=True)
      post = graphene.Field(schema.Posts)
      @classmethod
      def mutate(cls, root, info, id):
            post = models.Post.objects.get(id=id)
            if (info.context.user == post.added_by):
                  post.delete()
                  return f"{'ID':ID}"
            else:
                  return {'partial': True}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make mixin objects that are shared by multiple mutation classes.  This can help reduce boilerplate code, but if you only have two models it's not worth the bother.  Here's an example of this approach for a delete mutation:

```
class DeleteMutationMixin(object):
    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, root, info, **args):
        obj = cls.get_obj(args, info.context)  # This method needs to be implemented; see below
        obj.delete()
        return cls(ok=True)  # It's easier to implement if all child classes return the same thing. 


class DeleteComment(DeleteMutationMixin, graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.Int(required=True)
    
    @classmethod
    def get_obj(cls, args, context):
        # write a model specific method to return the object based on args
        # For example:
        return Comment.objects.get(args.get(id))
```

I have gone down this road, and I found that the mixin classes got more and more complex as number of classes that inherited from the mixin increased, which is one reason that recommend against this approach.  *On the hand*, this is a great way to enforce uniformity. You would be able to force all of your delete mutations, for example, to act the same.